# Get value from option field in contact form 7

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, return-value, contact-form-7

How can I  add value in option field in contact form 7? It should be show on view source code too.
I want value like If user select Apple, I want value as 122.
If user select Mango, I want value as 225.
If user select Banana, I want value as 330.

```
Apple|122
Mango|225
Banana|330
```

I have applied this top code. But I can't get value in view page source code.

Comment: The CF7 plugin dropdown does not have the possibility to include value attributes in its dropdown field.  You will need to use a plugin extension such the [Smart-grid layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension, which has a dynamic_dropdown field that includes value attributes in addition to option labels.